# Returning latest database ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, error-handling

I want my method to use a `finally` block so I can be ure that my EF entity is disposed after usage, even if an exception is thrown, but I would also like to not handle exceptions in that method.

1. The current code works but is it possible to omit the `catch{}` block? Would an exception from the `try{}` block be re-thrown or would it be forgotten?
2. Is it necessary to set `tm_entity` to `null` in the `finally` block, or will `Dispose` take care of everything?

Any other suggestions are welcome!

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns ID of the latest result database.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="managementEntity">EF Test Management entity.</param>
/// <returns>Latest result database ID.</returns>
public static int GetLatestDatabaseIteration(TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities managementEntity)
    {
        if (managementEntity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Passed entity can not be null!.");
        }

        TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities tm_entity = managementEntity;
        int? latestDatabaseID = null;
        try
        {
            latestDatabaseID = (from trb in tm_entity.TestRunsDatabases
                                select trb.DatabaseID).Max();

            if (latestDatabaseID == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot evaluate latest Test Result Database ID.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //Could I just omit this block?
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            tm_entity.Dispose();
            tm_entity = null; //is it necessary?
        }
        return (int)latestDatabaseID;
    }
```

EDIT:

After making suggested changes my method looks like this.

```
public static int GetLatestDatabaseIteration(TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities managementEntity)
    {
        if (managementEntity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Passed entity can not be null!.");
        }

        TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities tmEntity = managementEntity;

        int? latestDatabaseID = (from trb in tmEntity.TestRunsDatabases
                                 select (int?)trb.DatabaseID).Max();

        if (latestDatabaseID == null)
        {
            throw new NoRecordsFoundException("Cannot evaluate latest Test Result Database ID.");
        }

        return (int)latestDatabaseID;
    }
```

Changes I made:

1. I have renamed variables to match CamelCase.
2. I have removed .Dispose on a passed reference as it would also Dispose object in the Caller method.
3. I have abandoned calling generic exception and replaced it with custom one that more accurately describes this exception.

Calling .Max() if query return null may cause problems, but I will check it with UnitTests soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't rethrow caught exceptions like that.

```
catch (Exception ex) //Could I just omit this block?
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

Erases the call stack of the exception, instead use

```
catch (Exception) //Could I just omit this block?
    {
        throw;
    }
```

However the point is moot, because the try-finally block is [syntactically legal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx), but you should bear in mind a very major caveat (emphasis my own):

> Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run. However, **if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered**. That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

As such, it would be a good idea to make sure you catch any exceptions you can reasonably expect, but then that's just standard good practice.

As an aside, I really don't like your use of caps. Type names should be PascalCase, and you should avoid underscores in type names or variable names.

Lastly, you really should throw a subclass of `Exception`, and never the parent class.

Comment: I have mixed throw and throw ex all together. I have thought that throw ex will retain same stack but I was wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. Same goes for other things you pointed out, I must have missed this "tm_entity" somehow as I usually enforce CamelCase in my codebase. I'll post changed code soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

By calling `GetLatestDatabaseIteration(TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities managementEntity)` you are not passing an object of type `TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities` to the method but a reference of that object to the method.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708674/2655508

> Objects aren't passed at all. By default, the argument is evaluated
>   and its value is passed, by value, as the initial value of the
>   parameter of the method you're calling. Now the important point is
>   that the value is a reference for reference types - a way of getting
>   to an object (or null). Changes to that object will be visible from
>   the caller. However, changing the value of the parameter to refer to a
>   different object will not be visible when you're using pass by value,
>   which is the default for all types.
>
> If you want to use pass-by-reference, you must use out or ref, whether
>   the parameter type is a value type or a reference type. In that case,
>   effectively the variable itself is passed by reference, so the
>   parameter uses the same storage location as the argument - and changes
>   to the parameter itself are seen by the caller.

So by calling `tm_entity.Dispose();` you are basically disposing the original object.

```
private static void foo()
{
    TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities theEntity = new TEST_MANAGEMENTEntities();
    int latestID = GetLatestDatabaseIteration(theEntity);
    // now theEntity is already disposed
}
```

If this is what you wanted to do, then it isn't the right place. A consumer/caller of this method would not expect that the passed in "object" whould be disposed after returning.

If you are working with `IDisposable` objects you should use [`using` blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

**Naming**

In addition to `Nick Udell`'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70155/29371) please see the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) .

Comment: I wanted to keep object that was passed alive outside of the method so thanks for pointing that out! Yup I have noticed the error of using underscore and I do know that I should use using block for disposable items. I'll rethink my design of this class and post it later. Thanks for input once again!